# Very simple web service: take inputs, email results

Tags: c#, python, django, web-services

I work at a small startup as a Data Scientist, and I'm looking for ways to make my analysis a bit more visible/useful to the organization. I'd like to be able to put up a simple web service which allows internal users to run my scripts remotely. They should be able to input a few parameters via a very simple UI, and they should have the option to have the results appear in the browser window (after a possibly long wait), or have them emailed. Results may be a few pdf figures, and they may be Excel spreadsheets (maybe more exotic in the future, but this is it for now).

The scripts are going to be all in Python, which will handle the analysis.

So, I'd like to know what the pros and cons are of using C#/WCF vs. something like Django or Python. I have significant experience in C# working in the Client-side code base here, but I have much less experience with WCF. All of my analysis work is done in Python (and R, to a lesser extent). The main goal is to not take all of my time building a fancy web service/UI---the front end just has to be friendly enough to not intimidate the marketing people. I don't have to worry about encryption, the server will be behind our firewall. I'm pretty platform agnostic, but I think the servers are all Windows based, if this helps.

Thanks in advance.

---

For extra credit, how does your answer change if some of my scripts are in F#?

Comment: To this end, has anyone used Tornado before? (http://www.tornadoweb.org/)

Comment: why do you want to do this using a web service? why not creating a simple asp.net application?

Comment: Maybe "web service" isn't the right word. I want something that people can interact with via their browser. If you couldn't tell, I'm not very sure where to start...

Comment: if you do now want to expose your operations as services (in simple words they may write their own program to fetch data from your service); you may just write a simple asp.net client.

Comment: Well, I don't want the marketing guys writing any programs...they'll put me out of work :) I just want a simple web form to take inputs, and the ability to return pdf files and spreadsheets in the browser window, or (optionally) via email.

Comment: :) then go with asp.net; if you have used c# before, it is not very hard to grasp the concept.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the Django web framework. You could set up a small app with your python scripts as different views. https://www.djangoproject.com/

And if you don't want to put that much effort into creating a friendly UI you could use twitter bootstrap.  http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Then just run the app internally to gather and display data either via HTTP GETs or via e-mail.

edit: I'm sorry I did not read carefully "pros and cons are of using C#/WCF vs. something like Django". I recently made a Django app and it was fairly straight forward.

Comment: No--this is exactly the kind of feedback I'd like. Thanks a ton.